# How to Solve Wamp Server - 3 Showing Code Instead of Execute in Windows?

Tags: php, wamp

My wamp server showing source code instead of excute?

[image]

Any help?

Comment: you need to install php module.check link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12142172/apache-shows-php-code-instead-of-executing

Comment: @Naisapurushotham FYI -> https://snag.gy/E16DuM.jpg   what is mean 304 error, and i am using wamp 3, how can i navigate /etc/apache2/ regard your solution.

Comment: share your `phpinfo.php` file code

Comment: @Himanshu My Code : <?php  phpinfo();  ?> If i run with 127.0.0.1:8080 i am getting errror page like https://snag.gy/BZhbQ3.jpg

Comment: @Himanshu may i know how to navigate /etc/apache2/)

Comment: I hope so your using window and you have installed with default data so you can go into your C:\wamp

Comment: there you can find apache directory

Comment: @Himanshu  yes, i am using wamp 3, there i no Apache2 folder

Comment: have to go into wamp and checked any apache named folder

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88037/discussion-between-zus-and-himanshu).

Answer (score 0):

> Just go to : **`127.0.0.1:8080/dashboard/phpinfo.php`** in your browser url bar

or

> **`127.0.0.1:8080/?phpinfo=1`** using wampp

Comment: try this one @zus, no need to create a phpinfo page since phpinfo is already included in localhost server dashboard

Comment: 127.0.0.1:8080/?phpinfo=1 getting same error, 127.0.0.1:8080/dashboard/phpinfo.php return https://snag.gy/Q4KMIF.jpg

Comment: Updated httpd.cong file in chat @magefms